# phone gap android environment setup

Tags: android, java, cordova, android-sdk-2.1

I am try to get the android environment setup for phone gap and I keep getting this 
error when I try and create the phonegap project.

```
ruby bin/droidgap create MyTestApp

c:/phonegap-android/lid/create.rb:24:in ``: 

no such file or dirctory - androidsdk-path.bat android.bat 

(Errno::ENOENT) 

from c:/phonegap-android/lib/create.rb:24:in `guess_paths` 

from c:/phonegap-android/lib/create.rb:7:in `initialize` 

from bin/droidgap:24:in `new' 

from bin/droidgap:24:in `<main>'
```

I have got through the setup for the last could of days. 
I have also check the PATH for the android sdks and built the 
test android app in eclipse.

there are the path in the environment vars

C:\Ruby192\bin;
C:\apache-ant-1.8.1\bin;
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin;
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools;

any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to add "c:/phonegap-android/bin" to your PATH.

More info here: http://wiki.phonegap.com/phonegap-android-terminal-quickstart